# 2D games in OpenGL - coordinates

Tags: android, opengl-es

How can I do coordinates like in 2D games (so X = 0 Y = 0 in top, right corner)?
Something like this on the left:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to use some formulas to convert between the two coordinate systems.

```
openGL_x = (screen_x - width/2)/(width/2)   == a*x + b;
openGL_y = (height/2 - screenY)/(height/2)  == c*y + d;
```

With openGL you can embed these two linear equations into the ViewMatrix and work with pixel coordinates.